# ng-disabled not working for radio buttons and checkboxes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-disabled

I am working on an AngularJS application. I am trying to create a page that allows the user to select one of three radio buttons. Two of the three also have checkboxes underneath them to allow the user to select additional options if they've selected the appropriate radio button. To try to prevent improper checkbox selections, I'm trying to set the ng-disabled attribute on the checkboxes. So far, it's not working, and I've tried several different iterations.

This is my HTML:

```
    <div class="panel-body">
        <input type="radio" id="notFraudulent" name="actionSelector" ng-model="cleared" /><label for="notFraudulentRadio"> Not Fraudulent</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="highVolumeCustomer" ng-model="highVolumeCustomer" ng-disabled="(fraudulent||cleared)" /><label for="highVolumeCustomer"> High Volume Customer</label><br />
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" id="appearsFraudulent" name="actionSelector" ng-model="fraudulent" /><label for="isFraudulentRadio"> Appears Fraudulent</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="reportAccount" ng-model="reportAccount" ng-disabled="(cleared||reviewed)" /><label for="reportAccount"> Report Account</label><br />
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" id="markReviewed" name="actionSelector" ng-model="reviewed" /><label for="markReviewed"> Mark As Reviewed For Later</label>
    </div>
```

I have tried changing the operator on the ng-disabled expressions to &&, as I've seen some articles where it's suggested that the operators don't mean what one thinks they mean. But that doesn't work, and neither does it work if I put just a single condition in the expression. There isn't anything in the controller (yet) that tries to use or manipulate any of the ng-models in the HTML. I've come to the conclusion that there's something I'm missing with regard to the radio buttons, but I can't for the life of me figure out what.

Can anyone see what my mistake is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `value` property to bind special value for radio button, and when radiobutton's status is changed, the value will be kept at `ng-model`.

refer the code snippet below:

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.selectedValue = 'cleared';
    $scope.cleared = false;
    $scope.fraudulent = false;
    $scope.reviewed = false;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body" ng-app='app' ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="radio" id="notFraudulentRadio" name="actionSelector" value="cleared" ng-model="selectedValue" /><label for="notFraudulentRadio"> Not Fraudulent</label><br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="highVolumeCustomer" ng-model="highVolumeCustomer" ng-disabled="selectedValue === 'fraudulent' || selectedValue === 'cleared'" /><label for="highVolumeCustomer"> High Volume Customer</label><br />
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" id="isFraudulentRadio" name="actionSelector" value="fraudulent" ng-model="selectedValue"/><label for="isFraudulentRadio"> Appears Fraudulent</label><br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="reportAccount" ng-model="reportAccount" ng-disabled="selectedValue === 'cleared' || selectedValue === 'reviewed'" /><label for="reportAccount"> Report Account</label><br />
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" id="markReviewed" name="actionSelector" value="reviewed" ng-model="selectedValue"/><label for="markReviewed"> Mark As Reviewed For Later</label>
  <br>
  cleared:{{cleared}}<br>
  fraudulent:{{fraudulent}}<br>
  reviewed:{{reviewed}}<br>
  selectedValue: {{selectedValue}}
</div>
```

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks!